# Fechar activity após resultado

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou tentando implementar um tutorial utilizando [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) para ler **QRCode**.
[No tutorial](http://www.thiengo.com.br/integrando-o-leitor-de-qrcode-zxing-no-android) que estava acompanhando ele utiliza o **Eclipse** e coloca as *libs* do *ZXing* todas "à mão" importando. Eu estou utilizando **Android Studio** e utilizei o `Gradle` para gerar as dependências.

Mas chega um momento em que ele edita uma classe da *lib* do *ZXing* pois é necessário após tirar a foto do **QRCode** que retorne a `ActivityMain` para mostrar o resultado, caso contrário ele fica parado na `Activity` da câmera.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Eu não consigo encontrar onde o `Gradle` baixa as dependências para eu edita-la.
- Existe algum outro jeito de fazer com que após ler o **QRcode** a `Activity` feche?

**[Aqui](http://pastebin.com/pDipZDbe)** está o código como implementei.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa necessariamente alterar a classe `CaptureActivity`, você pode criar uma `Activity` sua que estende desta, e como a alteração é somente neste método, basta sobrescrever ele e implementar da forma como diz o tutorial.

Vamos supor que você crie esta nova `Activity` assim:

```
public class ScanActivity extends CaptureActivity {
    @Override
    public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor) {
        Intent it = getIntent();
        it.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", rawResult.getText());
        it.putExtra("SCAN_FORMAT", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, it);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Então, basta ao invés de chamar a `CaptureActivity` diretamente, chamar esta sua nova `ScanActivity`:

```
Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
```

Lembrando que você deve alterar também o `Manifest`, como indica no tutorial.

Comment: quando eu tentei estender a classe CaptureActivity da um erro falando que eu não posso usa-la como herança:"cannot inherit from final 'com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity'",pastebin do codigo:http://pastebin.com/SqEpQFNH,você sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Não havia reparado, parece que houve mudanças nesta biblioteca e agora essa classe é um **final** e não dá mais para estender. As alternativas então ficam em outras soluções como [esta](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) ou mesmo você importar manualmente esta biblioteca, sem o *Gradle*.

Comment: você conhece algum app que eu possa chamar um intent com ele e ele faça a leitura e me devolva o resultado?,pois com o ZXing não ta rolando :/